# Chrome on Ubuntu 13.04: click to select url in address bar. How to achieve this?

Tags: 13.04, google-chrome

Chrome on Ubuntu 13.04: click to select url in address bar. How to achieve this?
Default behavior in Windows is that it selects the complete url after one single left click.
While the same is not implemented in Ubuntu/Linux.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:

1. triple-click the url
2. press <kbd>F6</kbd>

Comment: Using `Ctrl+L` also works.

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware of that. I was looking to be able to change the default and be able to select with one single click. I hear this is possible with Firefox. So would like to know if something can be done with Chrome?